# Multiple inputs in fortran namelist files

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran code and I need to include multiple input files for a variable instead of one input file in the namelist. In other words instead of defining GB01.nc I need to define GB01.nc and GB02.nc as input files in the namelist as shown below:

OFFLINE_FILE    = 'GB01.nc',

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand what the NAMELIST input is specifying. You're providing a value for a character variable, not an "input file". What the program does with this value is up to the program, not related to NAMELIST input. The program may interpret OFFLINE_FILE as a file specification, but that's up to the program code.

If one assumes that the program simply passes this value as the FILE= specifier to an OPEN statement, then no, you can't give it multiple files. It's certainly possible that the program looks at the value and if it sees a comma list, it separates things out, but you'd need to read the code (or the program's documentation) to see if it has that feature.